# Фундаментальное непонимание назначения Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Привет. Последние несколько дней присматриваюсь к Webpack, что это такое я уже понял. Сборщик модулей, верно? Материалов по webpack огромное количество, как и восторженных отзывов. Но либо я не понял саму концепцию, либо я вообще ничего не понимаю в назначении модулей.
Постараюсь быть краток, надеюсь на ваше терпение и "развёрнутые" ответы.

Допустим, есть задача - сделать три web-страницы. Пусть на одной из них будет супер-крутая и сложная галерея-карусель. Я сделаю её с применением jQuery и какого-то плагина-carousel, на второй страничке у меня простенькая форма, для взаимодействия с которой, я так же использую jQuery, но уже без всяких плагинов, просто для манипуляции с элементами DOM. А на третьей вообще используется только нативный JS, просто потому что так захотелось.

В моём понимании, модульность - это нужная штука, которая позволяет разбивать скрипты и использовать их только там где нужно, по назначению. 
То есть, на первой странице я загружу мой модуль-скрипт, который объявит зависимости от Jquery и jquery-carousel и будет работать исключительно с галереей.

Никакого другого кода, например для работы с контролами формы со второй страницы я сюда подгружать не буду. Как на вторую страницу я не буду подгружать плагин для "карусели". А на третью страницу я вообще не буду подгружать jquery, раз он там не используется.

Значит я напишу три "модуля" для каждой страницы, а потом запущу Webpack, который услужливо соберёт мне всё в один файл и подключит абсолютно все зависимости и все модули?

А зачем мне тогда webpack? Я сам могу писать весь код в одном файле, что собственно и делаю. Или я что-то не так понял?

Answer (score 4):

> Сборщик модулей, верно?

Не совсем верно, это не просто сборщик, это часть экосистемы фронта, часто вебпак является центром этой самой экосистемы. Hot modules reloading, node static server c live обновлением работы etc.. это все очень важно для профессионального разработчика. Делать высоконагруженные проекты с сотнями модулей без применения способов стандартизации - выстрел себе в ногу. А особенно в коллективе других разработчиков.

> Пусть на одной из них будет супер-крутая и сложная галерея-карусель.

Избавьтесь от понятий "супер" "крутая" и "сложная", все это просто библиотека имеющая свой вес и зависимости которые при необходимости можно подключить к другим страницам.

> А на третьей вообще используется только нативный JS, просто потому
>   что так захотелось.

В команде разработчиков, так нельзя "просто потому что так захотелось" проект построенных на таких "внегласных костылях" при первом же масштабировании помрет.

> В моём понимании, модульность - это нужная штука, которая позволяет
>   разбивать скрипты и использовать их только там где нужно, по
>   назначению.

Не только, скоро браузеры научаться делать хорошо require и import и сборщики не так нужны будут, те проекты которые это учли, перейдут на нативный веб более бесболезненно. А вас будет портянка из `script src=...` Веб медленно, но верно идет к понятию веб компонентов.

> То есть, на первой странице я загружу мой модуль-скрипт, который
>   объявит зависимости от Jquery и jquery-carousel и будет работать
>   исключительно с галереей.

Поправочка, вы должны загрузить 1 минифицированный максимально оптимизированный файл, который при умелой настройке статики и кеширования будет отдаваться из кеша при повторной загрузке. Это конечно идеал, но к этому нужно идти. Скорость в конечном итоге много решает.

> Значит я напишу три "модуля" для каждой страницы, а потом запущу
>   Webpack, который услужливо соберёт мне всё в один файл и подключит
>   абсолютно все зависимости и все модули?

Это вопрос из вакума, то у вас за сайт? приложение? Если это набор из 3 html файлов без дальнейшей модификации для сугубо личных целей, то можете не заморачиваться с этим.

> А зачем мне тогда webpack?

Задайте этот вопрос в первую очередь к себе) И не забывайте, что помимо сборки js, есть еще куча других задач таких как: транспиляция языка (babel), проверка кода на ошибки и стиль написания (так называемые линтеры), работа с CSS пре/пост процессорами, прекомпиляция шаблонов и т.д. все эти задачи может решить вебпак.

> Я сам могу писать весь код в одном файле, что собственно и делаю. Или
>   я что-то не так понял?

Яму можно копать ложкой или лопатой или с помощью техники, кому как удобнее. Работа над большими проектами с сотнями зависимостей (это когда у вас модели, вьюхи, компоненты, стили и прочее по полочкам разложено) не представляется возможной без вменяемой системы сборки на webpack, gulp, grunt, nodejs а также пакетных менеджеров yarn или npm

Мой совет как разработчика, отвлекитесь от дискутирования и попробуйте собрать простенькое современное приложение на фронте, аля vue, angular, react, marionette можно попробовать различные виды рендеринга страниц и использование шаблонизаторов.

Comment: *yarn. И разверните в ответе тему babel, stylus и прочего. Ручками на них не попишешь, не пособираешь точнее, а хочется. На данный момент вебпак один из самый быстрых сборщиков.

Comment: Немного исправил, спасибо.